# Saving & Fetching CloudKit References

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm having trouble creating with CloudKit References. Data is being saved into CloudKit but its not referencing its parent (list). Don't know what i'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated!

**Saving Method**

```
var list: CKRecord?
var item: CKRecord?    

@objc func save() {
    let name = nameTextField.text! as NSString

    //Fetch Private Database
    let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase

    if item == nil {
        //Create Record
        item = CKRecord(recordType: RecordTypeItems)

        //Initialization Reference
        guard let recordID = list?.recordID else { return }
        let listReference = CKRecord.Reference(recordID: recordID, action: .deleteSelf)

        item?.setObject(listReference, forKey: "list")
    }

    item?.setObject(name, forKey: "name")

    //Save Record
    privateDatabase.save(item!) { (record, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.processResponse(record: record, error: error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Fetch Method**

```
var list: CKRecord!
var items = [CKRecord]()

private func fetchItems() {
    //Fetch Private Database
    let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase

    //Initialize Query
    guard let recordID = list?.recordID else { return }
    let reference = CKRecord.Reference(recordID: recordID, action: .deleteSelf)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: RecordTypeItems, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "list == %@", [reference]))


    //Configure Query
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    //Peform Query
    privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.processResponseForQuery(records: records, error: error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but have you tried looking at the CloudKit web dashboard to see if the reference is being saved successfully to the item record on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Where you are creating your query to retrieve items referencing the list, should the list reference in the predicate format string be inside an array? If you create the item's reference like `item?.setObject(listReference, forKey: "list")`, CloudKit will infer the `list` field to be a single `CKRecord.Reference`, so the query would be:

`let query = CKQuery(recordType: RecordTypeItems, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "list == %@", reference))`